# Toggling one button to adjust two values

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm designing a virtual simulation of a physical machine controller that only has a few face buttons.  I'm trying to get the arrow buttons to scroll through the menu and also modify the selected value when the enter button is clicked.  Right now, it functions as I want it to, but when it toggles back to menu control and you scroll through, the next value on the menu (i.e. **temperature 1,2,3**) is overwritten by the previous.  This is the snippet of code that currently controls the selected/unselected functionality, which is in an Enter Frame event listener:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXLXs.jpg)

```
//--SWITCHES BETWEEN SCROLL AND EDIT--//
if (changerSwitch == true)
{
    changerMenu = changer;
    minValue = menuMin;
    maxValue = menuMax;
    ScreenMain.selectedShade.visible = false;
    ScreenSmall.selectedShade.visible = false;
}
else
{
    changerValue = changer;
    minValue = valueMin;
    maxValue = valueMax;
    ScreenMain.selectedShade.visible = true;
    ScreenSmall.selectedShade.visible = true;
}

switch(mainMenuIndex)
{
case 0:
    break;
case 1:
    temperature1 = changerValue;
    break;
case 2:
    temperature2 = changerValue;
    break;
case 3:
    temperature3 = changerValue;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

`MainMenuIndex` is the reference number for the current menu option and set equal to `changerMenu`.  The up and down buttons just add and subtract 1 to the value `changer`.  The enter button just flips the `changerSwitch` Boolean.

```
//--FACE BUTTONS--//
WS_btn_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f1_MenuDown);

function f1_MenuDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
if (changer < maxValue)
{
    changer ++;
}
}

WS_btn_up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f1_MenuUp);

function f1_MenuUp(event: MouseEvent): void {
if (changer > minValue)
{
    changer --;
}
  }

WS_btn_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f1_MenuEnter);

function f1_MenuEnter(event: MouseEvent): void {
if (changerSwitch == true)
{
    changerSwitch = false;
    changer = changerValue;
}
else
{
    changerSwitch = true;
    changer = changerMenu;
}
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but I'm just trying to get results.  What do I need to do in order to get the value from the next selected menu option to remain unchanged?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're doing here.  Your question talks about using arrow keys to scroll through a menu, but there's no mention of a keyboard listener in your code.  Also, there's no hint as to what triggers the code you posted.  Maybe a screenshot of your menu would help?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear.  I edited it for a little clarity.  The arrow buttons I was referring to were the face buttons on the controller itself.

Comment: Thanks for editing!  Those details definitely help.  Is there anything other than the 'enter' button that will set new temperatures?

Comment: Not currently.  The user tabs down to the value they want to change, hits the 'enter' button, adjusts it with the 'arrow' buttons, and hits enter to switch back to menu navigation.

Comment: If you move your `switch` statement from your ENTER_FRAME listener to your f1_MenuEnter function, that should fix this.

Comment: That gets changing and saving values to work somewhat, and I think that gets me on the right track.  The main issue now is that scrolling through is not picking up the previous values. But I think I can add a `switch` to the arrow buttons to update the label on screen.  Thanks.